# Plotting a geotiff in python with a quiver plot overlay

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gdal, netcdf

I'm requesting insight on superimposing a quiver plot of velocities on top of an geotiff image. I've been using gdal to work with the geotiff, and netcdf4 libraries for the velocity data.

Thus far, I've used imshow() to plot geotiff, zoomed in on my study area. In the extent argument, x and y are numpy array's of the eastings and northings of the domain. Below is my code, and pic of my resulting figure.

```
# plot study area
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
fig = plt.imshow(data[:3,:,:].transpose((1, 2, 0)), extent =
        [x[1000],x[2000],y[750],y[2000]])
```

[image: imshow() figure of study area, zoomed in]

Within the model domain, I have velocity magnitudes of currents as a quiver plot, where `ee` and `nn` are the coordinates of the velocities in eastings and northings. The velocity and coordinate data are extracted from a netCDF file. Below is the quiver code, and a link to the quiver plot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.quiver(ee,nn,test_u,test_v, scale=75)
plt.show()
```

[image: quiver plot to overlay]

I want to overlay the velocity magnitudes on top in my geotiff. Below is my attempted code to do this. I believe my units of the imshow figure and my units of the quiver-plot aren't lined up correctly.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.imshow(data[:3,750:2000,1000:2000].transpose((1, 2, 0)),
       extent = [x[1000],x[2000],y[750],y[2000]])
plt.quiver(ee,nn,test_u,test_v, scale=75)
plt.show()
```

Any tips on how to get passed this hiccup are appreciated. How do I set my imshow units so the pixels match geographic coordinates, and how can I get this to match the units of the quiver plot. I'm somewhat new to working in python and the numpy, gdal, and associated libraries. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `extent` and set it to the actual units you have. Here, it seems that you simply have to multiply the data in `x` by 1000.

```
extent = [x[1000]*1000,x[2000]*1000,y[750]*1000,y[2000]*1000]
```

However, only you can know for sure how the coordinates `ee` and `nn` relate to the pixels of the image.